# Recursive function does not clear parameters in the second execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, recursion

I have some problems with a programing exercise, I am doing a function to found the divisors of a number like is show in https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1ximo_com%C3%BAn_divisor, the question is

Why if i execute:

```
print (div_comun_divisor(60))
```

I get:

> ([60, 30.0, 15.0, 5.0, 1.0], [2, 2, 3, 5])

But if i execute both lines:

```
print (div_comun_divisor(40))
print (div_comun_divisor(60))
```

I got

> ([40, 20.0, 10.0, 5.0, 1.0], [2, 2, 2, 5])
>
> ([40, 20.0, 10.0, 5.0,1.0, 30.0, 15.0, 5.0, 1.0], [2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2,
>   3, 5])

I can observe, that the first execution return correctly, but the second one takes the value of the first execution and then continue writing over the first values.

Here is the code:

```
def primos(limite):
    primos = []
    for numero in range(2, int(limite) + 1 ):
        if es_primo(numero):
            primos.append(numero)
    return primos


def es_primo(numero):
    for i in range(2,numero):
        if (numero % int(i))==0:
            # es divisible
            return False
    return True

def div_comun_divisor(resto, divisores = [], candidatos = []):
    lisprimos = primos(resto)
    if len(divisores) == 0:
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        divisores.append(resto)
    for primo in lisprimos:
        resto_antes = resto
        resto = resto / primo
        residuo = resto_antes % primo
        if (residuo == 0 and resto > 0):
            divisores.append(resto)
            candidatos.append(primo)
            break;
        else:
            resto = resto_antes
    if(divisores[-1] == 1):
        return (divisores, candidatos)
    else:
        return div_comun_divisor(divisores[-1], divisores, candidatos)

#print (primos(20))
#print (div_comun_divisor(40))
print (div_comun_divisor(60))
```

Could you help me checking is a bug in the interpeter. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok, if you change for this: `print (div_comun_divisor(40))
print (div_comun_divisor(60, [], [], True))` is done